# Subversion Problem on Mac OS X

Tags: svn, macos

This exists in my httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /svn>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /Users/iirp/Sites/svn
   Allow from all
   #AuthType Basic
   #AuthName "Subversion repository"
   #AuthUserFile /Users/iirp/Sites/svn-auth-file
   #Require valid-user

</Location>
```

This is working file

When I change this to:

```
<Location /svn>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /Users/iirp/Sites/svn
   #Allow from all
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   AuthUserFile /Users/iirp/Sites/svn-auth-file
   Require valid-user

</Location>
```

and when I access my repository through URL, it gives me the authentication screen but after that screen my svn repository is not showing up correctly.

to see message that it gives to me is:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@example.com and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

Comment: Check the error log of your Apache server for a detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have this conf:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn/SvnAuthzFile
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Repositorio de Subversion"
    AuthUserFile /var/svn/svn-dev-auth-file
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

You have to remember that each repository must be readable and writable by the 'apache' user.

I hope it helps you

Comment: I tired this dose not work ... even i cannot restart the apache service as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the user that apache is running as cannot read the auth file. You'll need to chown or chmod the auth file so that user can read it. Ideally the permissions on the file will only grant read not write on the auth file. This will prevent a exploit of the webserver from modifying the auth file.

Comment: I have assigned this file to user group www and gave the permission chmod 777 but its still not working..